# No server folder in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried creating a [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) application, and when I did do `rails new railname` I do get most of the folders to create. However, I do not see the server folder and running `rails s` comes up with an error message.

Is there a way to get them back?

Currently running Ruby 4.0.4 on Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no `server` folder in a Rails 4 app. What error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `cd to railname` and `rails s`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to understand the Ruby on Rails folder structure and how to start the Ruby on Rails server.

To create new application in Ruby on Rails:

```
rails new railname
```

Then it generates a Ruby on Rails folder structure:

```
railname
..../app
......../controller
......../helpers
......../models
......../views
............../layouts
..../components
..../config
..../db
..../doc
..../lib
..../log
..../public
..../script
..../test
..../tmp
..../vendor
README
Rakefile
```

Ruby on Rails will not generate a server folder. That's why there isn't any server folder.

To start the Ruby on Rails server, you simply enter in the railname folder

```
cd railname
```

prompt and hit `rails s` or `rails server` to run the Ruby on Rails server.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any folder named *server* in a Ruby on Rails application. You need to cd to your application root folder:

```
cd railname
```

And then run the command:

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to install [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and then `rails server` in the `railname` folder. I was then able to start the localhost:3000.